# Databricks Scala net.liftweb.json parse() cannot initial error

Tags: scala, lift, databricks, azure-databricks

I can't find anything else relevant on the web.
I tried this with both versions of lift 2.12 & 2.10

My cluster/notebook is in apache spark 2.3 & scala 2.11

this code

```
import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
import net.liftweb.json._
​
val s = """{"steve":"toby"}"""
val j = parse(s)
```

​
this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.liftweb.json.package$
```

Any help appreciated.  I can't find any positive way to affect this.

Comment: Do you have lift-json dependency in your class path?

Comment: How do I check?  I'm in Databricks as you can see.  I've never had to inspect class path on Databricks.

Comment: RajkumarNatarajan .

Comment: It must be in class path.  Running `import net.litfweb.json._`  works just fine. But if I intentionally break it and run `import net.liXtfweb.json._` crashes `object iXftweb is not a member of package net`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.3.0"`

Below is the same code

```
 import net.liftweb.json._
 val s = """{"steve":"toby"}"""
 val j = parse(s) //j: net.liftweb.json.JValue = JObject(List(JField(steve,JString(toby))))
```

Are you missing `net.liftweb.json._` here because there is two json literal one for `object` one for `package` so we have to use `package` one.
Let me know if this helps.

**Edit**

To add `liftweb-json` in *databricks*  you have to go to "workspace->create-> Library->[select source] as maven then ***search packages*** and add after that restart the cluster and then try to run your notebook.

And then try to run the below code

```
package example
import net.liftweb.json._
import org.apache.spark._
object BasicParseJson {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val s = """{"steve":"toby"}"""
val j = parse(s)
// try to log your j value and check
}
}
```

Comment: How & where do I implement the libraryDependency?  My liftweb version is 2.10-2.5.4  how does that change your edits?  My installation of liftweb was via Databricks Import Library from a Maven Coordinate.

`notebook:1: error: not found: value libraryDependencies
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5.4"
^
notebook:1: error: value %% is not a member of String
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "2.5.4"`

Thanks

Comment: @SteveLyle-CSG Please check my edit here, sorry to missout the `databricks` config